# Render an AngularJS directive only after $scope.myVar is defined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

When my AngularJS "page" loads, I fetch some data from the server and set it to the scope:

```
myApp.controller('somePage', ['$scope', 'User', '$routeParams', function($scope, User, $routeParams){

  // Get the user.
  User.get('1234').then(function(user){
    $scope.user = user;
  });

});
```

On my page, I have a directive that needs `$scope.user` to be defined.

```
<div>
  <user-profile-info></user-profile-info>
</div>
```

The directive:

```
myApp.directive('addActionButton', function() {
  return {
    scope: false,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      element.bind('click', function(){
        alert(scope.user.name);
      });
    },
    template: '<button id="foo">Say hi to {{ user.name }}</button>'
  };
})
```

Right now, the page renders the component before `$scope.user` is defined, so there are errors.

**How can I make this directive only render when `$scope.user` exists?** Or how can I make my page view only render once the controller is done getting its data?

EDIT: All the above code is greatly simplified so you don't have to read extra info - but still has the constraints I need for the component (e.g. link, template with attribute, scope with an ajax call).

Comment: add watch on scope.user and look at newvalue

Comment: but if it takes 5 seconds to get the scope.user value, then the component will still be broken until it is ready.

Comment: use ng-show for this purpose to hide invalid value

Comment: @DonnyP Can you show the code you have for your directive?

@Ulterior, even with a wrapping `ng-show` element, Angular will still compile and link the directive; so if the directive was throwing an exception before, it will still throw an exception. But it's the right idea, an `ng-if` with the condition `user !== undefined` should do the trick, since `ng-if` will explicitly stop compiling any nested directives..

Comment: I think you are more worried about  the  processing  rather than rendering. You could set up a 2 way binding and attach the promise, or you could use eventing to let directive know to kick off, or you could set a onetime watch on the data before initializing directive process. How does your directive looks like?

Comment: In `addActionButton` you can just use ng-click why are you manually binding clickevent?

Answer (score 8):

[ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) is meant for this:

```
<user-profile-info ng-if="user"></user-profile-info>
```

See this example:

---

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('somePage', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout){

  // Get the user
  // simulating delayed request, 3 secs
  $timeout(function(){
    $scope.user = {
      name: 'Shomz'
    };
  }, 3000);
  

}])
.directive('userProfileInfo', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      element.bind('click', function(){
        alert(scope.user.name);
      });
      alert(scope.user.name); // this would throw an error without ng-if
    },
    template: '<button id="foo">Say hi to {{ user.name }}</button>'
  };
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="somePage">
  <p ng-hide="user">Waiting for user data...</p>
  <user-profile-info ng-if="user">qwe</user-profile-info>
</div>
```

Comment: @Shornz - if I want ng-if to wait for multiple models, for example "user" and "question", how could I do that? `ng-if="user && question"` seems reasonable but is that correct angular?

Comment: Thanks this works :) let me read PSL's answer before accepting

Comment: You're welcome! No problem, @PSL writes great answers.

Comment: @DonnyP I think this probably is a precise answer for the exact purpose for this directive, i wrote my answer with all the options before the question was edited to include the directive :). It could probably be a question of how self contained this directive should be? Should the user worry about placing an  ng-if when needed or can the directive take care of itself? _shomz I never realized that.. thank you :)

Comment: Yeah the issue here is like @PSL pointed out regarding self containing. Still, I went with this solution in my use case and just ensured to comment it. Watches, events etc tends to add some extra code and bloat. Not really happy with either solution to be honest. Wished angular could deal with it for us, which I guess it will with the life hook events. Sadly on old version :(

Answer (score 3):

I think you are more worried about the processing inside the directive too early rather than rendering of the directive. You could set up a 2 way binding and attach the promise, or you could use eventing to let directive know to kick off, or you could set a onetime watch on the data before initializing directive process. SO basic idea is not to write processing code inside the directive linking function directly. Also a good idea to have a controller associated to the directive and trigger the init function in the directive controller once you have got the data.

A simple example with both one-time and promise approach.

```
.directive('userProfileInfo', function($q){
   return{
     /*Your configuration*/,
     scope:{user:"="},
     link: function linker(scope, elm, attrs){
        /*
         Promise way
        */
         //Set up data or promise, q.when will make sure it is always a promise, be careful about not setting values like null etc..
         $q.when(scope.user).then(init);
        /*
          One time watch way
        */
        var unwatch = scope.$watch('user', function(user){
             if(angular.isDefined(user)){
                 unwatch(); //Remove the watch
                 init(); //initialize
             }
        });
        function init(){
           //Initialize directive processing accessing scope.user
        }
     }
   }
});
```

and bind it as:

```
<user-profile-info user="user"></user-profile-info>
```

If you are using one time watch, keep the code as is, if using promise approach. bind the promise, i.e

In your controller:

```
 $scope.userPromise = User.get('1234');
```

and

```
 <user-profile-info user="userPromise"></user-profile-info>
```

And if you are worried about not rendering the directive at all just use `ng-if` on the directive element, as long as your directive priority is less than ng-ifs it will not render.